# spaCy: Error in Downloading English Models

Tags: python, pip, nlp, anaconda, spacy

I used Anaconda to install spaCy as per instructions given on [download page](https://spacy.io/usage/)
When I run the following code to download the English models

```
python -m spacy download en
```

I get the following error.

```
/anaconda3/bin/python: No module named spacy.__main__; 'spacy' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by forcing a download. 
You can try this code

```
python3 -m spacy.en.download --force all
```